# Lipschitz function in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ lipschitz function. Show given that $(t_0,x_0)\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R^n} $ there exists a unique solution: $$x' = f(t,x)$$
$$x(t_0) = x_0$$ defined throughout $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: See the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: @Git Gud Your suggestion misses the main point, which is; the solution is global. This follows instead from a basically trivial estimate and Gronwall's lemma.